# How to extract and decode base64 parameter in Varnish VCL

Tags: php, base64, varnish, varnish-vcl

In order to invalidate the cache, I'm encoding an url the following way:

```
$clean_url = base64_encode( $url );

http://url_of_the_varnish_host_to_clean/clean/url?v=$clean_url
```

I would like to catch this url to clean and decode it in my vcl file.
I catch the request this way:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/clean/url?v=")
```

But I have no idea how to catch the parameter and decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will at very least need [vmod_digest](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-digest) which provides `digest.base64_decode` function.

Also, your regex is a bit wrong, should be:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/clean/url\?v=")
```

That said, why does your invalidation logic has to be so complex? Why not do it standard way - i.e. check against matches of purger IP against defined ACL and invalidate the URL of PURGE request (not parameter).

Comment: The problem here is that we use varnish 3.0.2 and vmod_digest requires 4.2

Comment: The reason we use this system is that we can also invalidate hosts or specific parameters using host?v= or parameter?v=

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you can invalidate using your method that you cannot invalidate using the standard one. More examples?)